# Get ArrayList String number / Position to show in ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a ListView with 3 Column custom List adapter. Two of the Column data is from SQLite and one is to show the item position (Which is generated on the Custom List Adadter. The output was like this:

```
1         Keyboard        3
2         Mouse           6
3         Monitor         8
```

But now my case is I want to get this serial number 1,2,3 from the ArrayList. Not in the custom list adapter. So that I can send some other SQLite column instead of the serial number 1,2,3 in some cases.

```
package com.example.itsre.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list_view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list_view = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        ArrayList<String> list_with_number = new ArrayList<>();
        list_with_number.add("Keyboard");
        list_with_number.add("Mouse");
        list_with_number.add("Monitor");

        ArrayAdapter array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_with_number);
        list_view.setAdapter(array_adapter);
    }


}
```

So can I get the serial number from the ArrayList to show in the code above? Or I just create another Custom List Adadter (which doesn't contain the serial number generation inside)?

Comment: `list_with_number.indexOf("Keyboard");`

Comment: Can you show the adapter code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the index number and show it as the serial number. But as an array starts from 0 You have to add 1 to each time you show the index.

To create an array of serial numbers you can run a loop like this

```
 ArrayList<String> listWithSerialNumber = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list_with_number.size(); i++) {
            listWithSerialNumber.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        }
```

But i will suggest you go with recycler view. As its much better, simpler and more customizable. [Here](http://androidxp.info/android-recyclerview/) is a good example of recyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

if your serial number is always from 1,2,3 then you can use

arraylist.get(position+1);

or

if your serial number varies you can use like

arraylist.get(position).getSerialNo();

Answer (score 0):

This is the Best way

```
String names[]={"Keyboard","Mouse","Monitor"};

    ArrayAdapter array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    list_view.setAdapter(array_adapter);
```